# Remasterys xubuntu 11.10

Tags: xubuntu, installation, live-cd, remastersys

I made a remasterys dist-mode iso of Xubuntu, modded by myself ( I just installed compiz and little more )

I then made a CD from this iso and a bootable usb, by unetbooin,both of them show the same behaviour: when I choose installer directly, they start a Xubuntu LiveCD session (perfectly working) but I didn't see a way to launch an installation.

How can I do that? Is there's a command line to launch install wizard, or something like that?

Comment: Try Relinux, it's a fork of Remastersys and is a little more actively developed.  I had problems booting a remastersys distro, but no problems with relinux.  Make sure to read the INSTALL file and also the readme in usr/share/docs for info on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

the command to launch the installer is ubiquity, if the package is missing in your cd you can try installing it from synaptic